# Xamarin.Ios не переносится текст

Tags: ios, xamarin

Есть `uilabel` внутри стак вью. В label текст, который не помешается в 1 строку. Выставила `lines=0` и `linebreakmode=wordWrap`, но текст не переносится.

В чем может быть причина?

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проставить корректно `Contraint's`. Нужно указать какую ширину может занимать `UiLabel` и тогда текст обрежется по этой ширине.

В Вашем случае, я так понимаю, необходимо констрейнт ширины сделать равным ширине `StakLayout'a`